# Joining list element wise in a specific order

Tags: python, list

Given lists `a` and `b` in the following order:

```
a = ['','','something','']
b = ['apple','banana','cat']
```

I need list `b` to be replaced with elements of list `a` where there is none (`''`). The number of elements in `b` will always be equal to the number of nones (`''`) in `a`.

```
expected_result = ['apple','banana','something','cat']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `list.pop`:

```
a = ['','','something',''] 
b = ['apple','banana','cat']

[i if i else b.pop(0) for i in a]
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'something', 'cat']
```

Comment: That's clever. Even shorter: `[i or b.pop(0) for i in a]` assuming that there are no false-y values other than the empty string.